# Adjust the error bar in ggplot2::geom_bar to the right place

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

This is my R code:

```
data = read.csv("R_plot.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
                
ggplot(data, aes(x=Method, y=Ratio))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Group), stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width=0.5), width = 0.5)+
  geom_signif(y_position=c(0.6,0.7),xmin=c(0.85, 1.85), xmax=c(1.15,2.15),
              annotation=c("*","ns"), tip_length=0.04)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Ratio-SE, ymax = Ratio+SE), width=0.1, position = position_dodge(width=0.5))
```

[image]

I tried to change the value of the width but it didn't work.

Comment: Try with `geom_errobar(aes(..., group = Group), ...)` to dodge the error bars by `Group`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data best shared using `dput()` or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.